# Allowing broadcast through a Cisco 5508

Tags: broadcast, cisco-wlc

We recently installed WiFi thermostats that connect to a Delta eBMGR, which is connected via ethernet. They utilize the BACnet protocol, which is broadcast traffic. They are on their own subnet, but the AP's that the thermostats connect to are controlled by a Cisco 5508 WLC. The 5508 only has a checkbox to permit or not permit broadcast traffic. There is no options to allow broadcast for specific SSIDs, and everything I have researched says that it does not care about VLANs, and it will simply propagate the broadcast traffic to everything it can touch. The thermostats will not work without broadcast enabled, but enabling it will allow everything on the WiFi network to broadcast, and we have roughly a thousand clients daily.

My question is, is there any way to work around this? Our budget constraints mean that replacing the 5508 isn't currently feasible. We had the thought of using ACLs in an attempt to block the broadcast traffic, but I don't know if that's necessarily realistic to do since I believe Cisco layer 2 ACLs work by MAC address. Our network is almost entirely layer 2 separated with VLANs, and blocking ports by MAC address would stop other traffic as well. Is there a solution that I'm missing?

Comment: Devices on Wi-Fi already broadcast, necessary for IPv4 to MAC address resolution among other things. Broadcasts will not cross VLANs (a VLAN is a broadcast domain), and broadcasts cannot be routed.

Answer (score 0):

> They are on their own subnet, but the AP's that the thermostats connect to are controlled by a Cisco 5508 WLC.

*Own subnet* usually means *own VLAN = own broadcast domain*. Broadcasts do not cross broadcast domains nor can they be routed.

You need to either rearrange your end nodes so they connect to the same broadcast domain/VLAN/IP subnet, or change the protocol settings in such a way that routable unicasts are used (if possible). Generally, you should segregate your wireless traffic into multiple SSIDs and map each one to a wired VLAN.

> The 5508 only has a checkbox to permit or not permit broadcast traffic.

That setting is for broadcast (filtering) within the wireless network. Once bridged to Ethernet that setting doesn't matter.